# Python requests - cannot understand how the argument is passed

Tags: python, function, python-requests, arguments

I am using this code to get data from Twitter API.

The code works, but I cannot understand how.

Specifically, I cannot understand how the `auth=bearer_oauth` argument works, since I am passing a function. And how the function works, since I am calling it without its argument.

Sorry if this is too basic, but I could not find an answer.

```
import requests
bearer_token = "AAA"
api_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent"


def bearer_oauth(r):
    r.headers["Authorization"] = f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
    return r

def connect_to_endpoint(url, params):
    response = requests.get(url, auth=bearer_oauth)
    return response

query_params = {'query': 'test'}
json_response = connect_to_endpoint(api_url, query_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bearer_oauth` function is just setting the request's authorization header to the bearer token before the request is sent.

The code you provided essentially has the same functionality as this:

```py
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {bearer_token}"
requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

After you send the request, Twitter's server parses the authorization header and checks that the bearer token you supplied is valid and has access to the requested resources.

As for why your specific code works, `bearer_oauth` is an [authentication handler](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/authentication/#new-forms-of-authentication) that gets attached to the request. The handler gets called when the request is constructed. You don't need to pass the request object because the handler is part of it already.

If you're curious about the implementation, I'd read the internal code [here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/bda7f0171f8bba17989d3a2c28dfa9a9261b1b65/requests/models.py#L589). It looks like the request object is passed to the handler, which then modifies the request (in this case, by setting the authorization header), and then returns the modified request object back to the internal function preparing the request. Then, all of the modified request object's attributes are copied:

```py
# Allow auth to make its changes.
r = auth(self)

# Update self to reflect the auth changes.
self.__dict__.update(r.__dict__)
```

Since `__dict__` is an internal dictionary that holds all the attributes of a single object, everything that was changed about the request object in the handler function will be copied and included in the request before it is sent.

Comment: Thank you very much!
The second part of your answer is what I was looking for. 

I didn't understand the "handler modifies the request" part and all examples I found, before posting here, simply used a tuple (like your example with headers) or a standard function call.

Again, thank you!